# Facebook Ads API query to pull the adgroup my campignId and the adstats that suprrort them at the same time

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I am running the query below and it is returning all of the the adgroups associated  with this campaign ID which is provided, I am wondering would it be possible for me to get the ad-statics using the same query for all of the adgroups provided. if so how would i go about doing this. Please take into account I want the data to return all of the data for the adgroups and the statistic for that adgroup

```
act_10188168/adgroups?end_time=2013-06-02&start_time=2013-06-01&campaign_ids=[60074688]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need us the adgroupstats API with the list of ad ids received from the previous query.

https://graph.facebook.com/act_{ad_account_id}/adgroupstats?adgroup_ids=[JSON-encoded array of ad group IDs]